# Eclipse one JSP showing black but not others

Tags: eclipse, jsp, syntax-highlighting

One particular JSP file is now rendered in black&white when it used to be syntax colored
Other JSP files in the same project are rendered correclty.
I tried to cut portions of the code thinking of a syntax error, but it didn't change anything.

What can cause that behavior?

**Edit**:
Since the syntax was good and restarting Eclipse didn't help, I simply copy/pasted the code in a new file, deleted previous and renamed new to previous. Cheesy, but works.
I would still like to understand...

Comment: Check the Open With context menu on the file that opens in black and white--are you actually using the JSP Editor?

Comment: I just tried. `Open With` > `Text Editor` shows same symptoms indeed. Not sure why Eclipse made that decision since I never used that feature before. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently I just ran into the same Issue...

Adding this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
```

to my .jsp (and reopening the file) solved my problem.

And don't forget to open it in the **JSP Editor**

[image: JSPEditor]

Maybe you opened it in **Text Editor** last time?

Comment: I just had to do the second step.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. Do you include taglibs?

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%
```

Something like this could be the error ( no > in the end ). Are you in Java EE perspective?

If nothing helps, just create a new JSP, write some valid code(so syntax highlighting is assured) and then copy paste your "black&white" code into it. If the highlighting disappears, you can be sure you have some syntax mistakes.
Also the good old "restart eclipse" may also help.

Comment: I am not using tablibs. I am in Java perspective but JEE has the same issue. Copy/Paste in a new file renders correctly it has to be a file setting. Restarting Eclipse didn't help either ...